# For multivariate linear regression, what is the partial derivative for Mean Absolute Error?

Tags: multiple-regression, derivative, mean-absolute-deviation

What is the partial derivative for MAE for multivariate linear regression? I understand that for mean squared error (MSE) the partial derivative with respect to some $\theta_1$ would be $-\theta_1 \cdot (y_{\text{pred}} - y_{\text{actual}})$ assuming the the following version of MSE is used.

**MSE Cost Function:**

$$J(\theta_0,\theta_1)=\frac1{2m}\sum_{i=1}^m \left(h_{\theta}(x^{(i)})-y^{(i)}\right)^2$$

What is the partial derivative for $theta_1$ when the loss function is MAE instead of MSE?

**MAE Cost Function:**

$$J(\theta_0,\theta_1)=\frac1{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \left\lvert h_{\theta}(x^{(i)})-y^{(i)}\right\rvert$$

I've been trying to find this but I haven't had any luck. Would it just be $-(y_{\text{pred}} - y_{\text{actual}})$ for $\theta_1 > 0$, and $(y_{\text{pred}} - y_{\text{actual}})$ for $\theta_1 < 0$? Or is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: A MathJax tutorial for typesetting math: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: Do you want the partial derivatives with respect to $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering what the partial derivative with respect to some $\theta_1$ would be. My calculus isn't the best so I wasn't totally sure how to apply the chain rule here.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks!

Comment: Can you calculate the partial derivative for a simple linear regression with $MSE$ loss?

Comment: I'm familiar with how to calculate partial derivatives for MSE but I'm not 100% sure how it'd be done in the case of MAE. Applying the chain rule, you'd get $-\theta_1$ from the inner derivative, and then I believe the outer derivative would be $\frac{(y_{pred} - y_{actual})}{|y_{pred} - y_{actual} |}$, so the partial derivative would be the product of these two terms. But I'm not confident enough in my calculus to know if this is the case, and I haven't been able to find any resources online that address this (though there are plenty for MSE).